# populate dependent drop down list from database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to populate WILAYA dropList after a value is selected on MIKOA drop list. Here is what i did so far. But the drop down list is not populated onChange Event. what ım ı doıng wrong so far?

on `first.php`

```
<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
       function jazaWilaya (mkoa_value)
       {
           var xmlhttp = new XHMLHttpRequest ();
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
           {
               if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
               {
                   document.getElementById("wilaya").innerHTML= xmlhttp.reponseText;
               }
           };
           xmlhttp.open ("GET", "wilaya.php?mkoa="+mkoa_value, true);
           xmlhttp.send ();
       }

    </script>
</head>
```

Inside the same file, here are the 2 drop down lists MKOA & WILAYA

```
Mkoa:
<select id="mkoa" name ="mkoa" onchange="jazaWilaya(this.value);" >
    <option value = "chagua">Chagua</option>  
    <option>Arusha </option>
    <option value = "dsm">Dar-es-Salaam</option>
    <option value = "dodoma">Dodoma</option>
    <option value = "kagera">Kagera </option>
    <option value = "manyara">Manyara</option>
    <option value = "mbeya">Mbeya</option>
    <option value = "morogoro">Morogoro</option>
    <option value = "mwanza">Mwanza</option>
    <option value = "mtwara ">Mtwara</option>
    <option value = "pwani">Pwani</option>
    <option value = "shinyanga">Shinyanga </option>
    <option value = "tabora">Tabora</option>
    <option value = "tanga">Tanga</option>
    <option value = "zanzibar">Zanzibar</option>
</select> 
<br><br>

Wilaya:
<select id="wilaya" name="wilaya">
    <option>Chagua</option>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
        <option value = "<?=$row['wilaya_id']?>"><?php echo $row['wilaya_jina'];?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

And this is the query code in another php file called `wilaya.php`

```
<?php
    // put your code here

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if (!$con)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    $mkoa = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["mkoa"]);

    mysql_select_db("dalaliOnline", $con);
    $sql = "SELECT wilaya_jina FROM WILAYA WHERE mkoa_jina ='$mkoa' ";
    $result =mysql_query($sql, $con);


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following some updates to the question, here is my new answer. Original answer below is not relevant.

Your JavaScript can't do anything unless it has some output from your script to work with. A PHP variable is of no use to it. One solution would be to have wilaya.php create the new options for the select box using your original code for that:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if (!$con)
    {
      // we don't want to output anything if something goes wrong, it'll mess the select up
      die();
    }

    $mkoa = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["mkoa"]);

    mysql_select_db("dalaliOnline", $con);
    $sql = "SELECT wilaya_jina FROM WILAYA WHERE mkoa_jina ='$mkoa' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
    ?>
    <option>Chagua</option>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $row['wilaya_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['wilaya_jina']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Then your JavaScript replaces the select box contents with the output of wilaya.php.

<strike>You're sending the data as a GET request but you have an if statement checking for a POST variable in wilaya.php, so if (isset ($_POST["mkoa"])) is evaluating to false and nothing is running in that file. Obviously without details of your database I don't know whether this is going to work when you fix that but seems to me that's the place to start. So you'll need to use GET instead of POST to check that this is set, eg:</strike>

```
if (isset ($_GET["mkoa"]))
{
  // the rest of your code
}
```

(I assume below that code you have some output that the JS is using.)

Also, obligatory - the mysql_ extension is deprecated. Update to PDO or mysqli when convenient.

Comment: I didn't mean to keep is get there, pls check out the the edits on wilaya php. NB: even with the $_GET it won't run

Comment: See my update - is there any other code in wilaya.php which has an output?

Comment: wilaya.php doesn't output anythıng. it just take data from the database

Comment: Well there's your problem. The JavaScript isn't going to be able to do anything without some output from your script that it can use. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: I want the output to appear on the WILAYA dropdownlist; I kept an echo statement between the OPTION tags of the SELECT element

Comment: @Buzuka can u add this line on the first.php ate top `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` and tell us what error you got

Comment: @Buzuka if I'm reading you right then I think you've got a bit of a fundamental misunderstanding of how PHP works here. You can't "update" the $result variable and the select will update. PHP runs once when the page loads, the output is static. If you need to update things after that, then JavaScript has to get some output from a PHP script and update the elements.

Comment: @hevens u r here for long dear, i wanna make a point i dont want to post any answer as i am bit sleepy and dont understan the question fully , first may be i am wrong, but she is not including wilya.php in first php, but on other hand she is not getting error, so i am confuse,

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 - Buzuka is trying to update the second <select> element via JavaScript. The JavaScript (first code segment in original post) is making the call to wilaya.php to update the second select.

Comment: @hevens thanks for saving from another embrasment nice man. explain good, i cant upvote now as she did not get the solution but i will letter on, your answer, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code in wilaya.php:

```html
<?php
    // put your code here

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if (!$con)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    $mkoa = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["mkoa"]);

    mysql_select_db("dalaliOnline", $con);
    $sql = "SELECT wilaya_jina FROM WILAYA WHERE mkoa_jina ='$mkoa' ";
    $result =mysql_query($sql, $con);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
       <option value = "<?=$row['wilaya_id']?>"><?php echo $row['wilaya_jina'];?></option>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

And remove following code from first.php file :

```html
Wilaya: Should be
<select id="wilaya" name="wilaya">
    <option>Chagua</option>

</select>

Instead of Wilaya: 
<select id="wilaya" name="wilaya">
    <option>Chagua</option>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
        <option value = "<?=$row['wilaya_id']?>"><?php echo $row['wilaya_jina'];?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I did as directed , I can't find an error but the second lıst won't load. Is my Javascript code written correctly?

Comment: @Buzuka yeah your javascript code written correctly. but in your ajax call you need to echo or print your output in your server side script and written this response in your particular element through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving u one more example of a state and city when the user choose one state from the first select box than the 2nd select box appear with its corresponding city try this.
here is the `state.php` page.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("statename");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function showdetails(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (str==0)
  { 
 alert("please select state name");
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("showresult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","details.php?id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
SELECT STATE:
:<select name="sid" id="sid" onchange="showdetails(this.value)">
                <option value="0">Select State Name</option>
                <?php

                $sql="select sid,statename from state";
                $qry=mysql_query($sql);
                $num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
                if($num>0)
                {
                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $res['sid'];?>"><?php echo $res["statename"];?></option>
                 <?php
                }
                }
                 ?>
             </select>




 CITY NAMES:    
 <div id=showresult></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The  `details.php` page

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("statename");
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
$sql="select * from city where sid='$id'";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($qry);
?>
<select name="cid" id="cid">
                <option value="0">Select City Name</option>
                <?php
                if($num>0)
                {
                    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
                {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $res['cid'];?>"><?php echo $res["cityname"];?></option>
                 <?php
                }
                }
                 ?>
             </select>
```

Here is 2 tables here one is city table(cid, sid, cityname) another is state table(sid, state name) state table's sid is foreign key at sid city table

Comment: you posted the answer or some code which you think fit the answer??

Comment: Yes try this it may help you not the answer just like this above problem @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: sorry what you said, if i understood you correctly you said it may help me not the answer?? sorry if i got it wrong

Comment: this program is just like the above problem which started by @Buzuka. Copy the both page code and create database and table as instruct You ll be able to know what is this actually.

Comment: @sameerkumar I understand your example very well, there are slıght dıff between my current code and thıs, lıke the <dıv> tag, can you wrıte thıs code wıthout usıng extra dıv ? bse I don't want to alter the current dıv arrangements ın my work.

Answer (score 0):

your wilaya.php should look like:

```
<?php
    // put your code here

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if (!$con)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    $mkoa = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["mkoa"]);

    mysql_select_db("dalaliOnline", $con);
    $sql = "SELECT wilaya_jina FROM WILAYA WHERE mkoa_jina ='$mkoa' ";
    $result =mysql_query($sql, $con);


?>

<option>Chagua</option>
<?php
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row['wilaya_id']?>"><?php echo $row['wilaya_jina'];?></option>
<?php
       }
?>
```

in your first.php file change

Wilaya:

```
<select id="wilaya" name="wilaya">
    <option>Chagua</option>
</select>
```